# Tabify: How does Emacs decides where to place tabs?

Tags: tabs

I understand how Emacs can remove tabs when using the `untabify` command (simply place a number of spaces in the place of the tabs) but what I can't understand is how does it place tabs in the place of spaces? When you use `tabify` how does Emacs knows where to place tabs? At first I thought that if there were 4 spaces (or a particular number) then it would change them with one tab but clearly that is not the case (as I saw using `whitespace-mode`). Clearly it is logical that this doesn't happen but if that is not the case then how does Emacs decides where should tabs be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the description of `tabify`:

> A group of spaces is partially replaced by tabs
>   when this can be done without changing the column they end at.

So it seems like it's behaviour depends on `tab-width` variable.